# PanDoc - Force converting into markdown to use # and ## for H1 and H2 respectively

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I prefer the `#` and `##` for Headers 1 and 2 respectively. I'd like to make my instance of PanDoc respect that when it is converting from say `html` into `.md`

Right now it converts H1s in the older style

```
Header 1
========
```

Is there a way to change this behavior.

I use PanDoc via Atom primarily. Not sure if this will have an effect. In researching I have concluded that the Atom functionality is flowing from my macOS systems PanDoc installation. So modifying the behavior there ought to flow through. If not, I'd be willing to change my behavior and use pandoc from the terminal if need be.

Thanks.

Thanks to the responder with the answer (atx-style-headers) achieved via command line using:

`--atx-headers` flag

Further explanation is available [here at Pandocs documentation](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#setext-style-headers)

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
pandoc --atx-headers -o try.md try.html
```

The output file `try.md` should have only ATX-style headers.

Comment: Thank you. I am going to edit my entry with the link at pandocs documentation that explains this, which I just found as your answer came in. I appreciate it.

Comment: @ercfre that's an interesting way of doing things 
Could you mark the answer as accepted? (if you're still there)